# How Word2Vec works? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I've got a question about gensim **Word2Vec** and documentation doesn't help me.

For example in my block of text I have some sentences like:

```
<Word1> <Word2> <Word3>
<Word1> <Word2> <Word3>
<Word1> <Word2> <Word3>
         ...
```

And in some time I have a new sentence like:

```
<Word1> <Word2> <Word3> <Word4>
```

How can I detect this situation? (of course Word4 is in dictionary too)

My solutions:
1). I tried to find most similar words for each and see - if the next word is in this is - OK, otherwise - I can find Word4. I mean I will do:

```
model.most_similar('<Word_i>')
or
model.similar_by_vector('<Word_i>')
```

And in top of answer list I will get Word_i+1. But it doesn't work!
Because I thought that the words in the sentence after training will have quite similar coordinates and in top list Word_i+1 will be for Word_i.
But it's wrong. When I checked this solution and trained by all corpus of text I had a situation when Word_2 wasn't in top list for Word_1! My explanation that not the near words have quite similar coordinates, but words with contextual proximity have quite similar coordinates, it's not the same..

2). So my second solution is using **doesnt_match()**, which takes a list of words, and reports the one word which is furthest from the average of all the words.

```
print(model.doesnt_match('<Word1> <Word2> <Word3> <Word4>'.split()))
```

And yes - in this case the answer will be Word4! (so I detect this word)
But if I do it with:

```
print(model.doesnt_match('<Word1> <Word2> <Word3>'.split()))
```

The answer will be Word2 (for example). And if I again will explore top words for Word1 and Word3 I won't see Word2 in this lists, but this sentence (Word1 Word2 Word3) is normal.

So how can I detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand what's the question here but I'll try to explain word2vec concept and what does `most_similar` return and hopefully it will be beneficial.

So, let's consider situation that there are two sentences: `<Word1> <Word2> <Word3>` and `<Word1> <Word4> <Word3>`. When creating the word2vec model, we take the same number of words left and right of the target  (current) word and construct tuples like: (target_word, proximity_word). Let's say we want to observe the situation when the target word is the middle word. So for sentence1 we'll get `(<Word2>, <Word1>)` and `(<Word2>, <Word3>)` and for sentence2 we'll get `(<Word4>, <Word1>)` and `(<Word4>, <Word3>)`. This way we tell the model that `<Word1>` and `<Word3>` are in the context of the . Similarly, `<Word1>` and `<Word3>` are in the context of `<Word4>`. What that means? We can conclude that the `<Word2>` and `<Word4>` are in some way similar.

So if you call `most_similar(<Word2>)` you will not get  or  but  because word 2 and 4 are appearing in the same context. That said, you cannot expect that if you have the sentence `<Word1> <Word2> <Word3> <Word4>` and call `most_similar(<Word3)` to get vector of `<Word4>`. Instead you'll get some word that has appeared in the context of words 1, 2 and 4 (this context window depends on the size we specify before training). I hope this has been helpful and makes word2vec clearer.

Comment: And for what do we use **window** parameter? From documentation: "Maximum distance between the current and predicted word within a sentence."
What if window = 1? Does it mean, that we set to model that each pair of words will be context proximity?
As example: Word1 and Word2, Word2 and Word3 and so on?

Comment: No, that means how many words before and after the target word we consider when creating the tuples. So if `window=1` that is the case I described in the answer. If the `window=2` that means 2 words before and 2 words after the target word